# Error when using lambda in java 1.8

Tags: java, lambda

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(4, 5, 6, 7);
    list.forEach(x -> {
        x = x * 9;
        System.out.println(x);
    });

    JButton btn = new JButton("aa");

    ActionListener ae = e -> {};
    btn.addActionListener(ae);

    List<Student> stds = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i =0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        stds.add(new  Student((int)(Math.random()*100), (int)(Math.random()*100)));            
    }

    System.out.println("Original List");
    stds.forEach(x -> System.out.println(x));

    System.out.println("\nModified List"); 
    filter(stds,x->x.gpa>15).forEach(x -> System.out.println(x));

    System.out.println(convert(51,t->String.valueOf(t)));

}
```

this is my instructor code and it is 100% correct but its giving me error when I run it in my PC.I think problem is my IDE??

Comment: Also, class Student is missing. Please add it.

Comment: Have you confirmed you're using Java 8 to compile?

Answer (score 0):

i think this is wrong.

```
System.out.println("\nModified List"); 
filter(stds,x->x.gpa>15).forEach(x -> System.out.println(x));
```

What do you filter? You can use filter in streams.
For example:

```
list.stream().filter(your predicate).forEach(do something);
```

I think you want something like this:

```
stds.stream().filter(x->x.gpa>15).forEach(x -> System.out.println(x));
```